# Socket, read until \n. What if bytes in message happen to be \n and end reading prematurely?

Tags: sockets, networking

I plan to have a socket reading data until it gets to the \n character (In order to read individual messages from a data stream). What happens, however, if the message you're sending happens to have bytes that match the \n character? Won't that end reading prematurely and mess up everything? How do people usually read until a certain part in their data?

---

Ok, Joe provided a lot of good alternatives to reading till the "\n" character. (Now that I think of it, \n is probably only used for text based things)

> Quote Joe: There's a lot of choices here. 1) substitute something for the delimiter when it's part of the content. 2) pick a less likely delimiter than \n. 3) include a message length ahead of each message that you parse out. And

#3 seems like the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Kind of a vague question.  Are messages with "\n" allowed?  Is there a reason you're not just reading all the data off the socket?

Comment: Edited my post. The goal is to interpret individual messages from a data stream. (De-vagued!)

Comment: There's a lot of choices here.  1) substitute something for the delimiter when it's part of the content. 2) pick a less likely delimiter than \n.  3) include a message length ahead of each message that you parse out.  And others.